# How to solve this in R (combinatorial )

Tags: r

I have a sequence code the looks like the following

```
A   =   A   
C   =   C   
G   =   G   
T   =   T 
W   =   A or T  
S   =   C or G  
M   =   A or C  
K   =   G or T 
R   =   A or G  
Y   =   C or T 
B   =   C or G or T 
D   =   A or G or T 
H   =   A or C or T 
V   =   A or C or G 
N = A or C or G or T
```

I want to compute combinations of my sequences.

Here are a few examples of the  combinations I want to get:

```
Example 1 ATGTTTGARCCACGYATHCCTAC 

Example 2 CAACGTCGTAATAAGGAAGTTTAG 

Example 3 CAGGTTGAGTATYTWCAAATTAC

Example 4 AAACCATRATGCCATTATAATATTG
```

Please if you can provide me possible code for this, t will be a great help indeed.

Comment: `expand.grid` is your friend. good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `chartr` ro replace the characters

```
#Your string
x <- "ATGCTGATCGAGCTANATCGATCGGACTACY"

# Get all combinations of replacement strings
# paste together for chartr function
ex <- do.call(paste0, expand.grid(N = c("A", "T", "G", "C"), Y = c("C", "T")))

# koop through each combination , replacing the string
sapply(ex, chartr, old="NY", x=x)

#                                AC                                TC 
# "ATGCTGATCGAGCTAAATCGATCGGACTACC" "ATGCTGATCGAGCTATATCGATCGGACTACC" 
#                                GC                                CC 
# "ATGCTGATCGAGCTAGATCGATCGGACTACC" "ATGCTGATCGAGCTACATCGATCGGACTACC" 
#                                AT                                TT 
# "ATGCTGATCGAGCTAAATCGATCGGACTACT" "ATGCTGATCGAGCTATATCGATCGGACTACT" 
#                                GT                                CT 
# "ATGCTGATCGAGCTAGATCGATCGGACTACT" "ATGCTGATCGAGCTACATCGATCGGACTACT"
```

---

Updated for your extended example

```
# lookup table of replacements
lookup <- list(
A   =   'A' ,  
C   =   'C' ,  
G   =   'G' ,  
T   =   'T', 
W   =   c('A', 'T')  ,
S   =   c('C', 'G') , 
M   =   c('A', 'C') , 
K   =   c('G', 'T'), 
R   =   c('A', 'G') , 
Y   =   c('C', 'T') ,
B   =   c('C', 'G', 'T') ,
D   =   c('A', 'G', 'T') ,
H   =   c('A', 'C', 'T') ,
V   =   c('A', 'C', 'G') ,
N   =   c('A', 'C', 'G', 'T'))

# Get unique character that are in sequence
yourseq <- "ATGTTTGARCCACGYATHCCTAC" # example 1
uniq.char <- unique(strsplit(yourseq, "")[[1]])

# subset look up to only use characters found in sequence
# this will keep the exapnd.grid replacements more reasonable size
# find all combinations of these
# and paste together
ex <- do.call(expand.grid, lookup[uniq.char])
vec <- do.call(paste0, ex)

# Get all sequences
sapply(vec, chartr, old=paste(names(ex), collapse=""), x=yourseq)
```

Comment: Hi Dear Thanks If you fill it with unique charaters that will be a great help. thanks. Actually I am navie to R and just not able to fill the example with properly and getting errors. If you just please fill them and I can re run on my PC for example 1 then others will be more easy for me to replace and work Thanks

Comment: Im not sure I understand. If you copy and paste the code from above (particularly the edit) it should execute and output the sequences. To get it to work on a different sequence string all you need to do is edit the `yourseq <- ...` line.

Comment: Thanks dear... Its working... your help is appreciated  
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
s1="ATGCTGATCGAGCTA"
s2="ATCGATCGGACTAC"
sep="**"
t1=c("A","T","G","C")
t2=c("C","T")
```

Here is what you can do:

```
res=do.call(expand.grid, list(a=1:length(t1), b=1:length(t2)))
paste0(s1,sep,t1[res[,1]],sep,s2,sep,t2[res[,2]],sep)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1] "ATGCTGATCGAGCTA**A**ATCGATCGGACTAC**C**" "ATGCTGATCGAGCTA**T**ATCGATCGGACTAC**C**"
[3] "ATGCTGATCGAGCTA**G**ATCGATCGGACTAC**C**" "ATGCTGATCGAGCTA**C**ATCGATCGGACTAC**C**"
[5] "ATGCTGATCGAGCTA**A**ATCGATCGGACTAC**T**" "ATGCTGATCGAGCTA**T**ATCGATCGGACTAC**T**"
[7] "ATGCTGATCGAGCTA**G**ATCGATCGGACTAC**T**" "ATGCTGATCGAGCTA**C**ATCGATCGGACTAC**T**"
```

Comment: Thank you, Dear for your comments but I think I put my question not so clearly. Dear for seqeunce codes are A = A C = C G = G T = T W = A or T S = C or G M = A or C K = G or T R = A or G Y = C or T B = C or G or T D = A or G or T H = A or C or T V = A or C or G N = A or C or G or T Few examples of my sequences which I want to get combinations are Example 1 ATGTTTGARCCACGYATHCCTAC Examples 2 CAACGTCGTAATAAGGAAGTTTAG Please if you can provide me possible code for this It will be a great help indeed

Comment: sorry but I do not catch your point. The output is the same output you stated in your question.

Comment: Thanks Dear for your valuable comments and replying me. I have edited my question can you please have a look now to the question. 
Thanks